# Is there an API for soft erotic pictures?

Tags: api

Just a wonder I had, does somebody know an API which with we can retrieve soft free-to-use erotic photos and pictures ?

I have seen a lot of APIs and datasets, but never heard of this kind.

Looking for answers !

Kind regards,

Shade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not specifically a soft erotic API, but you can use flickr and I'm going to assume tumblr, to get what you are asking for.
flickr's API is incredibly stable, you'll just have to filter out what is/is not soft erotic. under the erotic tag in flickr, you'll get mixed results; heads up, some may be NSFW:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/erotic
I'm assuming tumblr because it has similar content as well as a stable API, however I'm not very familiar with it. Although I've seen quite an uptick in porn there lately, so if you do use tumblr you may have to double down on your filter(s).

Comment: Well, thanks ! It is really helping, I'll probably work with both flickr and tumblr APIS. Have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Unsplash. After registering for the API:

https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos

you can search by term, or by [collection](https://unsplash.com/explore/collections), which is like a tag:

(NSFW?) https://unsplash.com/s/photos/erotic

---

Unsplash has a very friendly license: https://unsplash.com/license

> All photos published on Unsplash can be used for free. You can use them for commercial and noncommercial purposes. You do not need to ask permission from or provide credit to the photographer or Unsplash, although it is appreciated when possible.
>
> More precisely, Unsplash grants you an irrevocable, nonexclusive, worldwide copyright license to download, copy, modify, distribute, perform, and use photos from Unsplash for free, including for commercial purposes, without permission from or attributing the photographer or Unsplash. This license does not include the right to compile photos from Unsplash to replicate a similar or competing service.